# Message box (accept/cancel) before downloading

Tags: javascript

For the moment on our website we have an image that says "download" with link to downloadable material.

The boss have asked me to make sure when people hit the "Download" image (alternatively it could be a form button) it should prompt with a message (JS message box) saying: 'I accept terms of use' with Accept and Cancel buttons. 'Accept' takes you to the download file and 'Cancel' just closes the message box.
I believe I have seen this before, it would be great if anyone could help me with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution could be to use default browser confirm dialog:

```
<a href="/download.pdf" onclick="return confirm('I accept terms of use')">Download</a>
```

Comment: Wow. Really elegant solution!

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what I needed. Thanks to all for your contribution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built-in `confirm` function.

```
if (confirm("I accept terms of use")){
    // proceed
} else {
    // cancel
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use a [confirm](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptconfirm.php) box that has a message like "By clicking OK you agree to our terms and conditions."

Answer (score 0):

To do the barebones of what you want to do, use a function like such:

```
function acceptedTermsAndConditions(eventObject) {
    var accepted = false;
    accepted = window.confirm('Your T&C goes here');
    if (!accepted) {
        if (eventObject.cancelBubble) {     // Cancel in IE
            eventObject.cancelBubble = true;
        }
        if (eventObject.stopPropagation) {  // Cancel in other browsers
            eventObject.stopPropagation();
        }
    }
    return accepted;
}
```

and attach it to the click-handler of the anchor tag surrounding the image.

The `cancelBubble` and `stopPropagation()` will prevent the click-event from occurring on other elements.

That said, JavaScript is probably not the best solution as any user can simply turn off JavaScript for your site. Should a user turn off JavaScript in their browser, your code will not execute and the download will proceed as normal with no prompting for T&C.

A more robust solution would be to change the link to call a different page and pass the image to download as a parameter (i.e., `tnc.aspx?image_id=xxx` or `tnc.php?image=xxx.jpg`, etc.).

The different page can then just be a form that displays the T&C and has to be submitted server-side for processing. If the server-side code determines that T&C has been accepted, re-direct to the image for download.

Hope this helps,

Pete